# Add variable to href link in my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use a variable (or to find another way) to use a variable into my href.

Can anybody help with that?

```
app.on('changeup:myNewTender', function(data){
    var urrl = "/#manage/"+data._id;
    $.pnotify({
        type: 'success',
        delay: 3000,
        text: '<a href=urrl>Your  tender has been published</a>'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String concatenation:

```
'<a href=' + urrl + '>Your  tender has been published</a>'
```

Comment: It is interesting how string concatenation was used 4 lines above

Answer (score 1):

You should use string concatenation using `+`. You should also surround the URL with quotes of some kind, since good practice states that HTML attributes should be quoted.

```
'<a href="' + urrl + '">Your  tender has been published</a>'
```